# Prove zero vector is a boundary point of $C_2 - C_1$ of two "(relative) distinct" and non-disjoint convex sets $C_1$,$C_2$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

A question similar to [previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2297116/prove-zero-vector-is-a-boundary-point-of-c-2-c-1-of-two-distinct-and-non-d) with a slightly different condition. Consider $\Bbb R^n$. This previous proposition is shown not true by [copper.hat](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/27978/copper-hat)

Given a convex set $C$ in $\Bbb R^n$, its affine hull is $A(C) = \{ax+by:x,y\in C, a,b \in \Bbb R, a+b=1\}$. A point $x\in C$ is said to be its interior point if there exists $d>0$ s.t. $B_d(x)\bigcap A(C) \subseteq C$; otherwise $x$ is a relative boundary point. $C$ is relatively open if every point $C$ is a relative interior point.

We say two convex sets are "distinct" if their intersection are only **relative** **boundary** **points** of $C_1$ and $C_2$. The problem is:

> Prove zero vector is a **boundary point** of $C_2 - C_1 = \{x_2 - x_1: x_2\in C_2, x_1 \in C_1\}$ of two "distinct" non-disjoint convex sets $C_1$,$C_2$.

---

**Attempt**: By [Christian Bueno](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/86451/christian-bueno)'s method, I recap the following until I got stuck.

> Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be as above ("distinct", non-disjoint, convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$). Clearly $0 \in C_1 - C_2$
>
> Now suppose for contradiction that $0$ is not a boundary point of $C_2-C_1$. Then there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_\epsilon(0)\subseteq C_2-C_1$. Let $s:C_1\times C_2\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be the subtraction map given by $s(v,w)=w-v$. This map is continuous so
>
> $$s^{-1}(B_\epsilon(0))\subseteq C_2 - C_1$$
>
> is open relative to $C_1 \times C_2$. Here "open relative" is a concept from real analysis. I believe this concept should be consistent with the idea of "relative open" w.r.t. affine hull above. **I have trouble to go from here to the desired result**.
>
> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since they are distinct we have $ri(C_1)  \cap ri(C_2) = \emptyset$ Thus,

$$ 0 \notin ri(C_2)-ri(C_1)=ri(C_2-C_1)$$

(see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556347/relative-interior-of-the-sum-of-two-convex-sets) for above identity)

Therefore $0$ is not only a boundary point, but also a relative boundary point of the set $C_2 - C_1$.

Comment: This is a great answer I am looking for!